# Squid на машине за роутером

Tags: squid, роутер, debian

Ситуация такая: есть роутер, за ним 3 машины, на одной из них Debian, на котором нужно поднять прозрачный Squid, гугл показывает только, как настроить сквид на машине, которая сама раздает интернет, но у меня его раздает роутер. Прошу объяснить и помочь или указать на how-to мануал.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --destination-port 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.{ВАШ IP}:3128
```

Затем в настройках сквиды нужно настроить порт 3128 и ip, вот с самим роутером нужно будет поплясать...

Необходимо сообразить трассу по 80 порту таким образом:

Локальный ПК ---> Роутер ---> ПК с проксей ---> Роутер ---> Интернет.А ещё проще поднять DNS на тачке со сквидой и прописать её шлюзом на все локальные машинки. В этом случае, правда, интернет будет доступен только при включённом ПК со сквидой. С другой стороны, если сделать, как Вы выразились, "прозрачную проксю", то при выключенном ПК со сквидой прокси не будет работать (логично, спасибо КЕП). Так что советую заводить по человечески интернет через машинку с проксёй, настроить iptables, bind9, apache2, СКУль-сервер и все остальные прелести (в меру своей распущенности).

В идеале картина: ИНТЕРНЕТ ---> Роутер (в бридже или в роуте с проброской портов на IP шлюза(ПК с проксей)) ---> Шлюз ---> Локальный ПК (конечный пользователь).

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, проброс портов в помощь. ) То есть настраиваем на локальном ПК, на роутере (сервере) пробрасываем необходимые для работы порты.